# Hypothesis testing in the comparison of two Gaussian ratio distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, survival, nonparametric, ratio

tldr:
[This question summarizes mine in a more concise way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174974/determine-the-significance-of-the-difference-of-the-ratio-of-results?rq=1)

I am struggling with this seemingly trivial question that goes as followed:

The data are time points at which 50% of my yeast culture has died (a chronological lifespan experiment). I have:

- 4 time points for a wildtype (control) yeast strain in standard
  growth conditions (**WS**)
- 4 time points for a wildtype yeast strain in the presence of a drug D (**WD**)
- 4 time points for a deletion strain in standard growth conditions (**DS**)
- 4 time points for a deletion strain in the presence of a drug D (**DD**)

The data is not paired and we can assume each set of time points to follow a normal distribution.
An example of data:

- WS: 8.5, 9.2, 9.5, 11.2
- WD: 20.3, 22.2, 23.4, 24.1
- DS: 6.2, 6.5, 6.9, 7.3
- DD: 9.6, 10.1, 10.5, 10.9

I can get the [Gaussian ratio distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Gaussian_ratio_distribution) of WD/WS and DD/DS but I also want to test whether the gene deletion (partially) affects the ability of the drug to extend life at a certain level of significance: so DD/DS < WD/WS. The null hypothesis would be **H0: DD/DS = WD/WS and α = 0.05**.

Questions:

- Can I derive a level of confidence for DD/DS < WD/WS based on the Gaussian ratio distributions and the number of measurements (n)? (Note: This ratio distribution itself is not necessarily normally distributed and in some of my cases rather heavily right-tailed, a consequence of more dispersed data)
- Can I use an alternative non-parametric test?

The big issue is that I don't have individual ratios to compare, something necessary for bootstrapping-based tests and rank tests. The moment I start combining individual measurements (e.g. DS1 (6.2) with DD1 (9.6)), I am working with data that centers around the mean of the ratios, not the ratio of the means. Although those two are almost identical in the majority of cases, it is for my control ratio, the one I use for each individual test, that they differ quite a lot (3 vs 3.5).

I am not a statistician and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ratios of Gaussian distributions are not generally Gaussian. For example, if the means are both zero, the ratio would be Cauchy, and in other cases are more complicated. In your case, you have some confounding factor as the results are correlated, did you rank them in ascending order or something?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response. As a newbie, I really appreciate the effort from people to help others out. In my case, the values are always between 4 (fast cell death condition) and 40 (very long survivors). The resulting ratios (mean(numerator)/mean(denominator)) are always between 1.3 and 5) I found out about Fieller's theorem and Taylor expansion approximation to at least get confidence intervals. The results are not correlated. They are indeed just ranked in ascending order.

Comment: What about doing something simple like two-way [ANOVA](http://www.biostathandbook.com/twowayanova.html)?

Comment: The issue with ANOVA (and bootstrapping, rank sum tests,...) is that I need to start combining individual measurements. For one strain, this means combining 4 numerator values with 4 denominator values (16 in total). If I use this on, for example, the Mann Whitney test, I get ridiculously small p-values (good for me, not so good for science) and the data is simply not independent anymore (1 numerator contributes to 4 ratio values). On top of that, the 16 permutations will center around the mean of the ratios while intuitively, the ratio of the means seems a better value to summarize the data.

Comment: BTW, welcome to the site. I am considered a newbie myself, although you might not think so looking at my posts. The pecking order on this site is daunting, and a lot of us are not professional statisticians. Those who are more seasoned are impressive indeed.

Comment: I am learning a lot on this site and often realize I underestimate the subtlety of even the basic aspects of statistics. As for the question, I am not very familiar with ANOVA and will look into it a bit more in detail. Ultimately, I can always stick with confidence intervals and leave the magical p-value for what it is.

Comment: OK, try Two-way ANOVA, if it is useless, let me (us) know, and we'll undoubtedly try something else, difference of proportions, whatever.